# JSF 2.2 file upload, cannot retrieve file name

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2.2, servlet-3.0

I have the next code:

```
<h:form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{bean.file}" "/>
    <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{bean.send}" />
</h:form>
```

I'm debugging my application with Eclipse, and I can see that my attribute "file" is uploaded properly, and in the expressions window I can see the file name using the method `file.getSubmittedFileName()`, however, in my code:

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class MyBean {

    private Part file;

    public void send() {
        String fileName = this.file.getSubmittedFileName();
        System.out.println(fileName);
    }

    public Part getFile() {
        return this.file;
    }

    public void setFile(Part file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

`fileName` takes an empty string.

How is this possible?

Comment: [mcve] please!!!

Comment: @Kukeltje I added more code. My form has more inputTexts and a couple of inputSelects, but nothing weird (no ajax events or similar).

Comment: But you are using spring... Sure that does not play a negative role here? Search for that